# Can we do Integration of Asana to lightning Salesforce web Component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am doing work on Javascript using Salesforce lightning Web Component. I want to know how I integrate Asana with these components. Is that possible?

Actually, I want to use the only javascript to do that integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few resources I would suggest looking into if you want to do a client-side integration with LWC.

First off, the developer guide itself talks about options as far as making callouts directly from [LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.js_api_calls), or via an Apex [[proxy][2](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_api_calls_apex)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_api_calls_apex). The key things here are if you want to do a direct-from-client integration, you need to be certain to enable the CSP trusted site [endpoint](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm). And if you integrate via an Apex proxy, you *must* use a named credential in your HTTP request.

It sounds like you're looking at using the direct-from-LWC option.

Once you're familiar with the docs, I'd recommend taking a look at the dream-invest sample [project](https://github.com/trailheadapps/dreaminvest-lwc) which shows a basic API callout integration [component](https://github.com/trailheadapps/dreaminvest-lwc/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/stockWidget/stockWidget.js) and util [module](https://github.com/trailheadapps/dreaminvest-lwc/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/stockUtils/stockUtils.js) using an API key for authorization.

Once you get a basic callout working, of course feel free to come back with specific questions if you run into difficulties. There can be a number of hiccups you might encounter like with CORS, or more rigorous authorization settings required with certain APIs.

Comment: How to call authorization code of asana using LWC js file?

Comment: @VaishaliGarg Typically, we'd recommend you take a stab using the docs (both from Salesforce and from Asana), then you can come back and ask a new question that includes what you've tried already. I'd like to suggest you have a read of this help topic which gives guidelines on what makes a good question on this site. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask